# Remove _class from mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc

We all know if we are trying to add a document via spring-mvc to mongodb, spring adds _class to track & facilitate future marshalling/unmarshalling of the document. In cases in becomes a overhead and one might want not to include _class in mongodb. The following simple spring config helps to avoid adding the _class in mongodb.

```
<bean id="defaultTypeMapper"
class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultTypeMapper">
<property name="typeKey"><null/></property>
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMongoConverter"
class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
<constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
<constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
<property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultTypeMapper"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
<constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
<constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="defaultMongoConverter" />
<property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" />
</bean>
```

One can easily find the config for mongodbFactory and mappingContext. So I have not added it here. Note the way I have included typeKey.

Comment: yeah, you can answer your own question - but it's more helpful to separate them.  what you posted is more of a hint, @inkriti.  would you consider rephrasing it as a question, and then placing the solution in a separate answer?

Answer (score 2):

The question is: how to suppress the _class entry that the spring framework adds to MongoDB objects to support polymorphism.   If you don't need polymorphism support, _class wastes spaces and introduces issues if you refactor your POJO / model classes to different packages.

The above example was close, but has a few errors (e.g. DefaultTypeMapper should be DefaultMongoTypeMapper and typeKey is a constructor-arg, not set as a property).

The following works for me...

```
<mongo:mongo host="hostname" port="27017">
    <mongo:options
        ...options...
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory dbname="blee" username="blee" password="blee" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<bean id="mongoTypeMapper" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey"><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoMappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />

<bean id="mongoConverter" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
  <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
  <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mongoMappingContext" />
  <property name="typeMapper" ref="mongoTypeMapper"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter" />
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: The code I have posted above also works for me. Initially I tried with the config that you posted above, but spring could not find DefaultMongoTypeMapper in the package. Hence I had to chage the config. I am using spring-data-mongodb-1.0.0.M4.jar.